# Javascript run once using if condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

What I'm trying to do is run the if statement once only and disable the statement. In my code if I click the button consecutively the if statement still get rendered. Why is that?

HTML:

```
<button onclick="appendMsg()">submit</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function appendMsg(){

  var triggerOnceforShare = true;

  if(triggerOnceforShare){
     triggerOnceforShare = false;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
    console.log(triggerOnceforShare);
  }

}
```

codepen:
    http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/uoBkI

Answer (score 7):

You should put your `var triggerOnceforShare = true;` outside the function, as global and it will works.

```
var triggerOnceforShare = true;
function appendMsg(){   
  if(triggerOnceforShare){
    triggerOnceforShare = false;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
    console.log(triggerOnceforShare);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `triggerOnceforShare` is re-initialized every time you run your `appendMsg` function - so it is always set to `true`.

The way to ensure it is only run once is to store the variable in a closure:

```
// Using the revealing module pattern
// we create a closure using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)
var appendMsg = (function() {
  // We store the boolean flag in this IIFE's closure scope
  var triggerOnceforShare = true;

  // And then we return a function from our IIFE to bind to our `appendMsg` var
  return function appendMsg(){
    if(triggerOnceforShare){
      // Which changes the value of `triggerOnceForShare` in *the parent's* scope
      triggerOnceforShare = false;
      document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
    }
  }
})();
```

In fact, this sort of pattern can be generalized into a function which decorates another function:

```
function once(f) {
  var hasRun = false;
  return function() {
    if (hasRun) { return; }
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

which we could then use to simplify our code:

```
var appendMsg = once(function appendMsg() {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+= "true<br />"
});
```

Comment: indeed global - local var problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Move the `var triggerOnceforShare = true;` from inside the function into outside

```
var triggerOnceforShare = true;
function appendMsg(){   
  if(triggerOnceforShare){
     triggerOnceforShare = false;
     document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
     console.log(triggerOnceforShare);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var triggerOnceforShare = true;
function appendMsg(){

  if(triggerOnceforShare){
     triggerOnceforShare = false;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
    console.log(triggerOnceforShare);
  }

}
</script>
```

Try this pls...

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare the variable outside the function **appendMsg()**

```
var triggerOnceforShare = true;

function appendMsg(){        

   if(triggerOnceforShare){
       triggerOnceforShare = false;
      document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML+=triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
      console.log(triggerOnceforShare);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the function gets ran when the function gets called, this includes the `triggerOnceforShare = true` statement.

You can either do this;

```js
function appendMsg() {
    if (appendMsg.ran)
        return;
    appendMsg.ran = true;

    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
}
```

Which saves the `ran` state to the function once ran, and if it's ran again, immediately `returns`.

Or you could do something more efficient. Modify your onclick to this; `onclick="appendMsg(this)"` and use this;

```js
function appendMsg(button) {
    button.onclick = null;
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += triggerOnceforShare + "<br />"
}
```

Which removes the handler from the button once ran.